# funcion looping if it finds more then one result

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a function that keeps looping if it finds more then 1 result in the first methods each loop:

```
schedule: function () {
  Meteor.call('getOneUser', Session.get("selectedEmployee"), function (error, mainResult) {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
    } else if (mainResult != undefined) {
      _.each(mainResult.schedule, function (schedules) {
        Meteor.call('timezoneChanger', schedules.from, function (error, result) {
          if (error) {
            console.log(error.message);
          } else {
            schedules.from = result;

            Meteor.call('timezoneChanger', schedules.to, function (error, result) {
              if (error) {
                console.log(error.message);
              } else {
                schedules.to = result;

                Session.set('foundSchedule', mainResult.schedule);
              }
            });
          }
        });
      });
    }
  });

  console.log("a");
  return Session.get('foundSchedule');
}
```

The following code logs "a" unlimited times. But when in my mongoDB I have only 1 collection of schedules, it runs only once (mainResult.schedule).

The template simply looks like this:

```
<template name="employee_schedule">
    Schedule:<br>
    {{#each schedule}}
    <div>{{from}} - {{to}}</div>
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

Comment: Holy moly, that is some *aggressive* indentation!

Comment: And a text book example of how more efficient bracing and promises would both make this a lot more readable.

Comment: @DesertIvy, is it better now? :-)

Comment: @jfriend00: promises? Just split this monster into three separate helpers as it should be anyway, and indentation will stay within the screen width.

Comment: Also, in the current form it would make a great example for coffeescript lovers.

Comment: @HubertOG - yeah, this is three sequential async operations which is very steamlined using promises.

Comment: @jfriend00: agreed, but in this particular case these async operations shouldn't be here, they should be moved to separate helpers (see my answer below).

Comment: If someone could show me how to use synced method calls that also returns a value, it would be great, because I don't get what you mean with how its supposed to be done. I'll add my template to the post to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

The probable problem is reactivity, assuming you use this method in a reactive context like a template helper.

You use `Session.set('foundSchedule', ...)` inside after each update, which triggers rerun of each reactive method that uses `Session.get('foundSchedule')` – which you do in the last line. To see whether this is the problem, comment out the `Session.set` line and check logs, the infinite loop should be gone.

To remedy this, serve the array in one helper, and the `from` and `to` parameters you set here in another helper used in the context of the array item. This should also decrease your code complexity significantly.

Comment: I don't get it, if I don't nestle the method calls like above the methods will not finish and alter their values before the return is called. Also, how come this works if I get one result from _.each(mainResult.schedule ... ) and not when I get two?

Comment: Did you try commenting out that line? What happened?

Comment: it stoped looping but then I also didnt get any values returned to my template.

Comment: Great. Now pass those values in SEPARATE helpers. That is, create a helper to get "from" field, call `timezoneChanger` in that helper and return the fetched value in the same way as you do with `foundSchedule` now – either in a separate Session variable, local variable + dependency, or local reactive array.

Comment: Sorry, but how do I call on a helper from a helper?

Comment: You don't. You call it from a template. `{{#each scheduleHelper}}{{fromHelper}}{{/each}}`. Within `fromHelper` you can use `this` to access local data context - that is, the array item.